# MySQL : Better Solution To Nested If

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the link :
[Types Of Triangle](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle)

My answer is:

**`SELECT IF (A = B AND A = C AND B = C, 'Equilateral', IF((A = B OR A = C OR B = C) AND (A + B) > C, 'Isosceles', IF (A != B AND A != C AND B != C AND (A + B) > C, 'Scalene', 'Not A Triangle'))) FROM TRIANGLES`**

So far, its correct but somehow I have used a messy nested **`IF`**.

My question is, is there a better way to solve in terms of elegance and efficiency? I'm kinda familiar with SQL queries for years now but its something that I seldom use since I'm more into front end development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a CASE statement and not a IF:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (A = B AND A = C) then 'Equilateral'
WHEN ((A = B OR A = C OR B = C) AND (A + B) > C) then 'Isosceles'
WHEN (A != B AND A != C AND B != C AND (A + B) > C) then 'Scalene'
ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END AS "Type of Triangle"
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Comment: You can leave out B=C in the Equilateral condition as it is clear from a=b and a=c that b must be equal c

Comment: Your spelling of Triangle is wrong in END AS "Type of Traingle". BTW, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN A = B AND A = C AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral'
            WHEN A = B OR A = C OR B = C AND (A + B) > C THEN 'Isosceles'
            WHEN A != B AND A != C AND B != C AND (A + B) > C THEN 'Scalene'
            ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END
FROM    TRIANGLES
```

Comment: You missed END mate :)